# How to change ListView height dynamically in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I need to change the height of a ListView dynamically in my app.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for change height and width dynamically so, try this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)(width),(int)(height);
        listView.setLayoutParams(mParam);
```

you can also use LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT or LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT instead of height & width

Comment: the hereover solution give me a casting error, changing to LinearLayout works great.


LinearLayout.LayoutParams mParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,myList.size()*100);  listViewPhone.setLayoutParams(mParam);

Comment: @Dr.Luiji I have using something like this `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                item.getRoutes().size() * 200);` . But I am unable to see some item from the list. Any suggestion, I want to display whole list item of the list. What can I do ?

Answer (score 30):

This piece of code helped me to achieve dynamic listview height.

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.MeasureSpec;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Utility {
    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

In the main Activity use this Utility class to change the listview height.

```
 phraseListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.phrase_listview);
 phraseAdapter=new PhraseListAdapter(this);
 phraseListView.setAdapter(phraseAdapter);
 Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(phraseListView);
```

Taken from [here](http://kk-brothers.blogspot.com/2011/09/dynamically-change-listview-height.html)

Comment: Perfection Simplified. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too. Actually i am using Listview inside scrollview in one big form. That's why i have to use this code other wrap wrap_content value in listview height property works best. Anyways nice utility good job :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use below method to set the height of listview programmatically as per your items:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        />
```

Method used for setting height of listview:

```
public static boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView) {

        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter != null) {

            int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

            // Get total height of all items.
            int totalItemsHeight = 0;
            for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
                View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
                float px = 500 * (listView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
                item.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int)px, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            // Get total height of all item dividers.
            int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() *
                    (numberOfItems - 1);
            // Get padding
            int totalPadding = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();

            // Set list height.
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight + totalPadding;
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
            listView.requestLayout();
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Then set it like below code:

```
MenuAdapter menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(context, R.layout.menu_item);
            lvMenu.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
            setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(lvMenu);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Why did you multiplied with 500? What is the reason for doing "float px = 500 * (listView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);" ??

Answer (score 2):

First thing to keep in mind is that while getting height of listview using mylistview.getmeasureheight, it always gives height according to the textview/View inside the list which was set during initializing of adapter. So we need to declare the adapter as follows:

```
myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myarraylist){
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView textView = ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1));
            textView.setMinHeight(0); // Min Height
            textView.setMinimumHeight(0); // Min Height
            textView.setHeight(100); // Height
            return view;
        }
    };
```

Now height is fixed to 100. Note that it's the height of text and not the view itself. So keep it in mind when adding padding.
Now set the Adapter:

```
mylist.setAdapter(myadapter);
```

Now after every time you add an item to your list call a function as follows:

```
myarraylist.add(ds.getKey());
myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mylist.setAdapter(myadapter);

setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(mylist);
```

define the function in same class as:

```
public static boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter != null) {

        int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

        // Get total height of all items.
        int totalItemsHeight = 0;
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
            View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            float px = 500 * (listView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            item.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int)px, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        // Get total height of all item dividers.
        int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() *
                (numberOfItems - 1);
        // Get padding
        int totalPadding = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();

        // Set list height.
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight + totalPadding;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

You can also check if height is set or not correctly by returning true/false. This solution worked for me. Hope this Helps!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new control that extends the listview overwhriting some functions

```
public class WrapContentListView extends ListView {
    public WrapContentListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public WrapContentListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public WrapContentListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);
        setHeightWrapContent();
    }

    public void setHeightWrapContent() {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, this);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = this.getLayoutParams();

        params.height = totalHeight
                + (this.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        this.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/mzlogin/WrapContentListView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/mazhuang/wrapcontentlistview/WrapContentListView.java

Answer (score 0):

Personaly I spent so much time trying to find a solution, turns out all I had to do is to set my listview's height to wrap_content.

Answer (score -4):

use customized listview and give height as wrap_content.