# Android ExpandableListView inside ScrollView not expand full height

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, expandablelistview

I'm developing an Android app with a left slide menu contains some `LinearLayout` and a `ExpandableListview` in the middle like this image

[image]

The child view of `ExpandableListview` contains a `TextView` and a `ListView` below, ListView's visibility is gone in default. When click on the `TextView`, `ListView` will be visible.

The problem is that when click on the parent view of `ExpandableListview`, the list's height also expand to wrap it's content. But when click on child view (also `TextView`), the list'height doesn't change and I have to scroll down to see the last item.

To set height of ExpandableListview inside ScrollView, I used this code:

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        if(listItem instanceof SecondLevelExpandableListView)
            Log.e("abc", "SecondLevelExpandableListView");
        if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
            Log.e("abc", "ViewGroup");
            listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

**Screenshot of problem**

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem, I need the list always to wrap it's content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

when you expand animation ends,
call this:

```
listView.smoothScrollTo(x,y);
```

you can find the y with listView.getScrollY - maxY on Screen Seen

Comment: No. I mean that the listview always display all item and don't need to scroll.

Comment: So can you try again what is your problem?

Comment: My problem is that when I click on the Texview to visible the list below, the height of ExpanableListview doesn't extend to wrap it content. I want the ExpandableListview's height also extend like when I click on it's parent view.

Comment: I updated the screenshot on the question, the listview's height doesn't extend and the content is hided

Comment: here you can read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071131/how-to-change-the-height-of-the-listview-dynamically-in-andrtoid

Comment: as you can see on my question, I also use the dynamic set height for listview but its not works with the child view of ExpandableListview

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the Snippet for ExpandableListView

    import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ExpandableListView {

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded()) {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
            // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}



****
use <classpath for ExpandableHeightListView 
attribs
/>

*****
ExpandableHeightListView expListView = (ExpandableHeightListView)findViewById(id);
```