# Dynamically allocating height of for list view

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have one list view and one expandable list view and i want to show both on same view (I can fix the height of list view but that will scroll my list inside that defined height only).
i have these below link so far but by using this method it allocation blank space although it is allocating dynamic height.
http://kk-brothers.blogspot.in/2011/09/dynamically-change-listview-height.html

Comment: can you please upload some screenshot. Is it like one linearlayout listview on top and expandable on bottom?

Comment: here is link http://prntscr.com/c4dzst

Comment: You can create this layout using `expandable listview` itself. You can keep some of the item expanded all the time without group icon. It is not good to use two AdapterView in one screen. It slow down screen rendering.

Comment: one is list view and other is expandable list view i need to allocate height for both list dynamic. you are right i should not use two adaptor but it is my requirement.   do u have any suggestion or alternate solution , i need to show that way only .

Comment: Create expandable list view, by default open first item ingredient. set your group icon and group click listener accordingly.

Comment: As i said, i need the height dynamic for both list ,leave the expandable list view assume it two list view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26501296/797534

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120704/discussion-between-param-and-pr38y).

Answer (score 0):

Please check padding/margin also get place in calculation. Conversion of dp into px also required. But I will request not to design like this. It will destroy recycling property of your listview/recyclerview.