# How to set the dynamic height to list view

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, toggle

hello everyone i need help to set the the dynamic height to the list view .

In my task there a listView inside scroll view so i need to set the dynamic height to the list view to make the task complete workable in the scroll view.

Im using the below code from [how to change the height of the ListView dynamically in andrtoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071131/how-to-change-the-height-of-the-listview-dynamically-in-andrtoid).
This code is working good but problem is with this code it make the duble height to list view .

suppose if there only **3 items** in list view then it make the listview height equals to **6 items**.

i want know how to resolve it.

Here is my code.

```
 public class Utility {
       public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
           ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
           if (listAdapter == null) {
               // pre-condition
               return;
           }

           int totalHeight = 0;
           int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
           for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
               View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
               listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
               totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
           }

           ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
           params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
           listView.setLayoutParams(params);
           listView.requestLayout();
       }
    }
```

And im using it in listview activity Like:

```
SimpleAdapter simpleadapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), alist, R.layout.fragmentsrow, getItems, setItems);

        ListViewWelcomePage.setAdapter(simpleadapter);

        Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListViewWelcomePage);
```

Comment: First of all if you are using listview then remove Scrollview. By default if more data is there in list then it will scroll.

Comment: i need scroll view bro i can't remove scroll view just because there another items below the list view that i need to display using the scroll view

Comment: Use footer or header in list view instead of nesting list view in scroll view. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-a-footer-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

You can user ExpandableHeightListView instead of normal ListView.
Please see this github library https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/ExpandableHeightListView