# Listview in listview, custom height code not working (height based on child)

Tags: android, listview

I know listview in listview have height issue with wrap_content property not working.

I use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26501296/7354469) to fix my code, but it doesn't work.

> This is my logcat. (when i scrolled my parent listview)
>
> I have 3 listview, so it indicate level 0, level 1, level 2.
>   add {number} indicate " added item's height is {number} "
>
> 12-22 21:13:57.368 - ~~~~~ : this is level of 0
>   12-22 21:13:57.372 - ~~~~~ : add 857
>   12-22 21:13:57.375 - ~~~~~ : add 2159
>   12-22 21:13:57.378 - ~~~~~ : add 1109
>   12-22 21:13:58.569 - ~~~~~ : this is level of 1
>   12-22 21:13:58.597 - ~~~~~ : add 1109
>   12-22 21:13:58.602 - ~~~~~ : add 1088
>   12-22 21:13:58.606 - ~~~~~ : add 1895
>   12-22 21:13:58.608 - ~~~~~ : add 944
>   12-22 21:13:58.616 - ~~~~~ : add 1349
>   12-22 21:14:00.244 - ~~~~~ : this is level of 2
>   12-22 21:14:00.255 - ~~~~~ : add 449
>   12-22 21:14:00.258 - ~~~~~ : add 584
>   12-22 21:14:02.168 - ~~~~~ : this is level of 0
>   12-22 21:14:02.173 - ~~~~~ : add 335
>   12-22 21:14:02.179 - ~~~~~ : add 581
>   12-22 21:14:02.186 - ~~~~~ : add 1109
>   12-22 21:14:05.870 - ~~~~~ : this is level of 1
>   12-22 21:14:05.876 - ~~~~~ : add 1109
>   12-22 21:14:05.881 - ~~~~~ : add 1088
>   12-22 21:14:05.887 - ~~~~~ : add 719
>   12-22 21:14:05.892 - ~~~~~ : add 944
>   12-22 21:14:05.897 - ~~~~~ : add 503
>   12-22 21:14:07.123 - ~~~~~ : this is level of 2
>   12-22 21:14:07.128 - ~~~~~ : add 449
>   12-22 21:14:07.131 - ~~~~~ : add 584
>   12-22 21:14:08.799 - ~~~~~ : this is level of 0
>   12-22 21:14:08.811 - ~~~~~ : add 335
>   12-22 21:14:08.818 - ~~~~~ : add 581
>   12-22 21:14:08.824 - ~~~~~ : add 1109

but I have exactly same height's item. (57dp)

what is my problem..??

now, i just use below code to solve this problem.

```
// params = listView.layoutParams, metrics = DisplayMetrics()
params.height =
    (57*metrics.density*adapter.count + listView.dividerHeight * (adapter.count - 1))
listView.layoutParams = params
listview.requestLayout()
```

It can't work at various height. this is not cool

Comment: try listview.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: ah, that is kotlin code.

Comment: `ListView in ListView`... that's an ExpandableListView!

Comment: So, is the approach I think is totally wrong...?

Comment: Why re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: no... I just want listview in listview. child listview doesn't support scroll property.. I don't need to implement without expandable, but i want to try it. now, my curiosity is why that code not working..