# How to dynamically change the height of the ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

I have a question about the height of the ListView.the layout is as follows：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:onClick="scroll"
        android:text="Scroll" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The initial state of the page：

[image]

But when I clicked the “Scroll” button, I executed the code `linearLayout.scrollTo(0, 600);` , and the layout became like this:

[image]

The height of the ListView is not filled with the remaining layout，How do I solve this problem ? Thanks ！！！

Comment: Use a FrameLayout if you want elements to be able to overlap each other.

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: look for this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071131/how-to-change-listview-height-dynamically-in-android%22link%22) might help you

Comment: @SurajVaishnav I want to achieve a photoPicker like instagram.The top half is the selected image, the bottom half is the album displayed using the GridView layout, and the entire layout can be swiped up or down.